# Voltdb - Kafka Importer - Change delimiter used to import

Tags: apache-kafka, voltdb

I have a kafka topic delimited by ";" and I want to import to a voltdb table.

I did not find in the official documentation anything about change the delimiter. The Kafka Importer (https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/exportimportkafka.php), give me only two options: CSV and TSV.

Is there any advanced configuration that allows me to only change the delimiter?

My deployment.xml:

```
<import>
    <configuration type="kafka" enabled="true" format="csv">
        <property name="topics">br-com-topic-ws</property>
        <property name="procedure">AUT.insert</property>
        <property name="brokers">liXXXX:9092</property>
    </configuration>
</import>
```

Example of my Kafka Topic:

> 000000ADS;20160202;20050202235900;18.99;99
>   000000JAM;20160202;20150201235900;18.05;20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KafkaImporter uses a CSV/TSV Import Formatter by default, which as a [few options](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/exportimportformatcsv.php), but doesn't have configurable options for the delimiter.

You can implement a custom decoder to handle other formats.  We have some test code that include an example custom formatter on Github [here](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/tree/master/tests/test_apps/kafkaimporter).  There is a run.sh that includes a function jars that will build an OSGI bundle containing the custom formatter code.  The build uses ant, which uses the build.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you implement you own import formatter see example [here](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/tree/master/tests/test_apps/kafkaimporter/custom_formatter/formatter)

to configure it use this example [deployment file](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/blob/master/tests/test_apps/kafkaimporter/deployment-custom-import-formatter.xml)